# counting days since price change for product

Tags: r

I am trying to add a variable to my dataset, that counts the days since last price change for every product.

This is how the data looks like:

```
df <- read.table(text = "productid date price
1         2019-09-01     3.99
1         2019-09-02     6.99
1         2019-09-03     6.99
2         2019-09-01     6.99
2         2019-09-02     6.99
2         2019-09-03     3.99
2         2019-09-04     3.99
2         2019-09-05     6.99
3         2019-09-01     3.99
3         2019-09-02     3.99
3         2019-09-03     3.99", header=TRUE)
```

I tried the following:

df$price_count <- ave(seq_along(df$productid, df$date), d1$productid, df$price, FUN = seq_along)

But this approach doesn't start to count from 1, if the price for the same product changed to a price that has been set for the product before. e.g. row 8: price of 6.99 at the 5th sep 2019 for productid 2.

I expect the resulting dataframe to be:

```
df_result <- read.table(text = "productid date price count_days_since_price
1         2019-09-01     3.99 1
1         2019-09-02     6.99 1
1         2019-09-03     6.99 2
2         2019-09-01     6.99 1
2         2019-09-02     6.99 2
2         2019-09-03     3.99 1
2         2019-09-04     3.99 2
2         2019-09-05     6.99 1
3         2019-09-01     3.99 1
3         2019-09-02     3.99 2
3         2019-09-03     3.99 3", header=TRUE)
```

I appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `group_by` `productid` and every change in `price` using `data.table::rleid` and create a new column with `row_number()` of each group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(productid, group = data.table::rleid(price)) %>%
  mutate(count_days_since_price = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group)

#   productid date       price count_days_since_price
#       <int> <fct>      <dbl>                   <int>
# 1         1 2019-09-01  3.99                      1
# 2         1 2019-09-02  6.99                      1
# 3         1 2019-09-03  6.99                      2
# 4         2 2019-09-01  6.99                      1
# 5         2 2019-09-02  6.99                      2
# 6         2 2019-09-03  3.99                      1
# 7         2 2019-09-04  3.99                      2
# 8         2 2019-09-05  6.99                      1
# 9         3 2019-09-01  3.99                      1
#10         3 2019-09-02  3.99                      2
#11         3 2019-09-03  3.9                       3
```

To create groups we can also use `lag` instead of `rleid`

```
df %>%
  group_by(productid, group = cumsum(price != lag(price, default = first(price)))) %>%
  mutate(count_days_since_price = row_number())
```

Answer (score 2):

**1) Base R** This uses only base R.  It uses `ave` to apply the indicated function by `productid` where that function uses `sequence` applied to `rle` to generate the number of days since price change.

```
df_result2 <- transform(df, count_days_since_price = 
   as.integer(ave(price, productid, FUN = function(x) sequence(rle(x)$lengths))))

identical(df_result, df_result2)
## [1] TRUE
```

**2) rleid** We can simplify using `rleid` from data.table:

```
library(data.table)

df_result3 <- transform(df, count_days_since_price = 
  as.integer(ave(price, rleid(productid, price), FUN = seq_along)))

identical(df_result, df_result3)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: thanks a lot, both solutions work perfectly for me! (There is a slight difference regarding the handling of NAs in the variable price - I did not integrate price NAs in my question, because I will drop them later. But maybe its important for someone else: The rleid solution also counts NAs in a row whereas the BaseR solution handles each NA in a row as a new price resulting in 1 for each day in a row with price NA.)

Answer (score 1):

Using a similar logic as @Ronak Shah, however, with just `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
 group_by(productid, grp = with(rle(price), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
 mutate(count_days_since_price = 1:n()) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-grp)

   productid date       price count_days_since_price
       <int> <fct>      <dbl>                  <int>
 1         1 2019-09-01  3.99                      1
 2         1 2019-09-02  6.99                      1
 3         1 2019-09-03  6.99                      2
 4         2 2019-09-01  6.99                      1
 5         2 2019-09-02  6.99                      2
 6         2 2019-09-03  3.99                      1
 7         2 2019-09-04  3.99                      2
 8         2 2019-09-05  6.99                      1
 9         3 2019-09-01  3.99                      1
10         3 2019-09-02  3.99                      2
11         3 2019-09-03  3.99                      3
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this in `data.table` with `rleid` and `rowid`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, count_days_since_price := rowid(productid, rleid(price))]
df
#    productid       date price count_days_since_price
# 1:         1 2019-09-01  3.99                      1
# 2:         1 2019-09-02  6.99                      1
# 3:         1 2019-09-03  6.99                      2
# 4:         2 2019-09-01  6.99                      1
# 5:         2 2019-09-02  6.99                      2
# 6:         2 2019-09-03  3.99                      1
# 7:         2 2019-09-04  3.99                      2
# 8:         2 2019-09-05  6.99                      1
# 9:         3 2019-09-01  3.99                      1
#10:         3 2019-09-02  3.99                      2
#11:         3 2019-09-03  3.99                      3
```

Comment: thanks a lot akrun, your solution also works perfectly for me!